# How to deal with PHP Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in field.default.inc when implementing custom widget?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom auto-complete widget that I use to create a custom field that is used to create a custom content type in a custom module.

I have [hook_field_widget_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7)

```
function MODULE_field_widget_info()
{
    return array(
        "MODULE_taxonomy_autocomplete" => array(
            "label"         => t("MODULE Autocomplete term widget (tagging)"),
            "field types"   => array("taxonomy_term_reference"),
            "settings"      => array(
                "size"              => 60,
                "autocomplete_path" => "taxonomy/autocomplete",
            ),
            "behaviors"     => array(
                "multiple values"   => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

I have [hook_field_widget_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7)

```
function MODULE_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element)
{
    $tags = array();
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $tags[$item["tid"]] = isset($item["taxonomy_term"]) ? $item["taxonomy_term"] : taxonomy_term_load($item["tid"]);
    }

    $element += array(
        "#type"                 => "textfield",
        "#default_value"        => taxonomy_implode_tags($tags),
        "#autocomplete_path"    => $instance["widget"]["settings"]["autocomplete_path"] . "/" . $field["field_name"],
        "#size"                 => $instance["widget"]["settings"]["size"],
        "#maxlength"            => 1024,
    );

    return $element;
}
```

I have [hook_field_widget_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_error/7)

```
function MODULE_field_widget_error($element, $error, $form, &$form_state)
{
    form_error($element, $error["message"]);
}
```

Here I am creating the field of the content type

```
field_create_field(
    array(
        "field_name"    => "field_MODULE_tags",
        "type"          => "taxonomy_term_reference",
        "bundles"       => array(
            "node" => array(
                "CONTENT_TYPE",
            ),
        ),
        "cardinality"   => "-1",
        "settings"      => array(
            "allowed_values" => array(
                array(
                    "vocabulary" => "TAXONOMY_LIST",
                    "parent"     => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);

field_create_instance(
    array(
        "field_name"    => "field_MODULE_tags",
        "entity_type"   => "node",
        "label"         => "Tags",
        "description"   => "",
        "bundle"        => "CONTENT_TYPE",
        "widget"        => array(
            "weight"    => 1,
            "type"      => "MODULE_taxonomy_autocomplete",
            "settings"  => array(
                "size"              => 60,
                "autocomplete_path" => "taxonomy/autocomplete",
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

All of this appears to work fine, the content type shows the correct field, the auto complete works great, but when I try to save a new node of the custom type, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot unset string offsets in /modules/field/field.default.inc on line 41
```

If I look at field.default.inc file I see

```
function field_default_extract_form_values($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items, $form, &$form_state) {
  $path = array_merge($form['#parents'], array($field['field_name'], $langcode));
  $key_exists = NULL;
  $values = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form_state['values'], $path, $key_exists);
  if ($key_exists) {
    // Remove the 'value' of the 'add more' button.
    unset($values['add_more']);
    $items = $values;
  }
}
```

where line 41 is `unset($values['add_more']);`

If I output `$values`, I get a string where unset is expecting an array.

How can I make my value an array?

I've tried using hook_form_alter to add a custom submit function so I can manipulate the value but the custom submit never gets fired (which is weird).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hook_node_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) was how I was able to fix this issue.

```
function MODULE_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state)
{
    foreach ($form as $field => $field_data)
    {
        $field_info    = field_info_field($field);
        $instance_info = field_info_instance("node", $field, "CONTENT_TYPE");

        // since this field returns a string when an array is required, we need to correct
        // the data here before it goes any further.
        if ($instance_info["widget"]["type"] == "MODULE_taxonomy_autocomplete")
        {
            // Recieved: string
            // Expecting: array(array("tid" => TID),)
            $tag_names = explode(",", $form_state["values"][$field][$node->language]);
            $form_state["values"][$field][$node->language] = array();
            foreach ($tag_names as $tag)
            {
                $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($tag, $field_info["settings"]["allowed_values"][0]["vocabulary"]);
                $term = array_shift($term);

                $form_state["values"][$field][$node->language][] = array("tid" => $term->tid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens in [`field_default_extract_form_values`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.default.inc/function/field_default_extract_form_values/7) which is trying to load default values from the field, therefore to make it array, you need to make sure `#default_value` is in the right format.

This error usually happens when `#default_value` is NULL, but array is expected. So you can always cast it into array something like:

```
"#default_value"        => (array)taxonomy_implode_tags($tags),
```

Below is code example for radios/checkboxes-like widget with array() and with field element validation handler as per [@Scott](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/96661/1908) suggestion (which seems to make the difference as well):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function foo_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $value_key = key($field['columns']);
  $has_value = isset($items[0][$value_key]);
  $required = $element['#required'];
  $multiple = $field['cardinality'] > 1 || $field['cardinality'] == FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED;

  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'foo':
      $options = array(0 => t('Foo 1'), 1 => t('Bar'));
      $properties = _options_properties($instance['widget']['type'], $multiple, $required, $has_value);
      $default_value = _options_storage_to_form($items, $options, $value_key, $properties);
      if (!$multiple) {
        // If this is a single-value field, take the first default value.
        $default_value = $default_value ? reset($default_value) : array(); // <-- default array() here.
      }
      $element += array(
        '#type' => $multiple ? 'checkboxes' : 'radios',
        '#default_value' => $default_value,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#properties' => $properties,
      );
      break;
  }

  $element += array(
    '#value_key' => $value_key,
    '#element_validate' => array('foo_field_widget_validate'),
  );

  return $element;
}

/**
 * Form element validation handler for options element.
 */
function foo_field_widget_validate($element, &$form_state) {
  if ($element['#required'] && $element['#value'] == '_none') {
    form_error($element, t('!name field is required.', array('!name' => $element['#title'])));
  }
  // Transpose selections from field => delta to delta => field, turning
  // multiple selected options into multiple parent elements.
  $items = _options_form_to_storage($element);
  form_set_value($element, $items, $form_state);
}
```

---

In rare cases the *field.default.inc* error can be related to corrupted structure of your *form state*. This can either by caused by invalid implementation of [hook_field_widget_form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/155894/1908) or modifying/replacing `$form`/`$form_state` in [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) by reference.

---

#### Debugging

Debugging of invalid form state can be challenging. This can be achieved by PHP debugger (such as XDebug) and analysing structure of `$values` in `field_default_extract_form_values()` when the error happens (which suppose to be an array, not a string).

This can also be achieved by dumping the field instance which failing, for example:

```
--- a/modules/field/field.default.inc
+++ b/modules/field/field.default.inc
@@ -37,6 +37,9 @@ function field_default_extract_form_values($entity_type, $entity, $field, $insta
   $key_exists = NULL;
   $values = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form_state['values'], $path, $key_exists);
   if ($key_exists) {
+    if (!is_array($values)) {
+      var_dump($values, $field, $instance); die();
+    }
     // Remove the 'value' of the 'add more' button.
     unset($values['add_more']);
```

Or if Devel module is present, using `dsm()` or `dd()` is more convenient. For example can use `dd($form_state['values']);` to dump the whole structure of values into the file and compare the output between working and non-working scenarios.

For example (in shell) you can try:

```
> /tmp/drupal_debug.txt # Empty Devel debug file.
# Now test the working scenario to generate the dump.
cp -v /tmp/drupal_debug.txt working.txt
> /tmp/drupal_debug.txt # Empty the file again.
# Now test non-working scenario.
cp -v /tmp/drupal_debug.txt non-working.txt
diff -u working.txt non-working.txt # Or use GUI like: diffmerge, opendiff or meld
```